# How can I block requests for a file or directory unless it comes from a specified file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have the following RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]
```

These work well for blocking direct access to `txt|md|mdown` file types and the entire `site/` directory.

That said, I'm working on building out an `.appcache` file to cache my site for offline viewing and need to be able to access these files and directories from the  `.appcache` file. I have the `.appcache` file set up and I'm getting the following error in the browser:

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (-1) http://website.com/site/panel/blueprints/home.php
```

Is it possible to update the RewriteRule to allow for access from this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yoursite.com.br/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(pdf|cdr|indd|psd|jpg|jpeg|ai|zip|rar|7z)$ - [F]
```

just replace yoursite.com for your site and .*$ for the specific file that you need.

Comment: put the .htaccess on the directory where the files are downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files "file_name.appcache"> 
  // rewrite yours in it
</Files>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Not sure I understand… Where does this go?

Comment: May need further details here. Unfamiliar with this technique, and what I should do with `// rewrite yours in it`.